# servlet on eclipse asks me "do you want to save this file or find a program online to open it" when run on server

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat6

**When I try to run a Servlet by using "Run on Server" eclipse asks me "do you want to save this file or find a program online to open it**

screenshot
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EkJrxfmKEVE/UUXq9D2my-I/AAAAAAAAAbU/NZlNSnP3lTA/s1366/servlet.jpg

there is no problem with the code. please help me, am unable to figure out...
same problem was faced by another guy...
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/669271/

still problem is unanswered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled your content type.
Since the browser doesn't know how to display `test/html`, it offers to save it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
res.setContentType("test/html");
```

will be

```
res.setContentType("text/html");
```

Note that "test" was changed to "text".